# how to show only the time in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table that has date field.  When I run a query, I see this:

> 01/10/2009 22:10:39

How can I retrieve only the time (IE: 22:10:39)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(yourval, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') FROM yourtable;
SELECT TO_CHAR(yourval, 'HH:MI:SS') FROM yourtable;
```

**Edit:**
as @steven pointed out, to have 24 hours style use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(yourval, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the format `HH24`, since `HH` is only a 12 hour date.

```
select to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') from dual

select to_char(YourDateColumn, 'HH24:MI:SS') from YourTable
```

Answer (score 4):

SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh:mi:ss')
  FROM DUAL

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_COLUMN,'HH24:MI:SS') from TABLE;