# Oracle Database cursor not retriving correct date with time

Tags: sql, oracle, database-cursor

I have a Database cursor as follows:

```
CURSOR fetchquotedate(account_id IN NUMBER)
    IS
        select distinct(quotedate) 
        from mytable
        where customer_number= 12345;
```

The `quotedate` value in mytable is: `7/27/2020 4:00:00 PM`

```
fetch fetchquotedate into l_qDate;
```

But when cursor inserts into `l_qDate`, `l_qDate` is only getting date: `7/27/2020`, not the time.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server?

Comment: What Data Type are l_qDate and l_qDate?

Comment: Kindly add the Oracle tag to your Question. Also post information about the table definition. It would be helpful if you could post a pl/sql example that will show exactly how you are doing this. Are you getting the value in an IDE or printing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show only the time in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568406/how-to-show-only-the-time-in-oracle)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing column after it with parentheses won't change anything and is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(quotedate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS A.M.') AS quotedate
```

Add `TO_CHAR` function to your query. The `quotedate` field is probably a DATE type column in your table and therefore, is not retrieving the time.

Comment: Thank you for response. I am able to retrieve quotedate with to_char with date and time: 07/27/2020 16:00:00 P.M.. but once I retrieve it as to_char, how can I set date in another table as date with time. i.e. how can I convert this to_char value into a date with date and time? e.g. quotedate = 07/27/2020 16:00:00 P.M.. I need to set this value in another table field expdate. This is a date field. I need to save 07/27/2020 16:00:00 P.M. as expdate with date and time.

Comment: Do you mean to use `TO_DATE` function?

Comment: yes. I need to convert retrieve 07/27/2020 16:00:00 P.M value back into date format to save in a Datbase column of date type. Thank you.

Comment: @techie_ns Why would you want to make it a char and then back to a date? I think it would help you to edit your Question as I previously mentioned, so it's clear what you're trying to do. (Also adding another question on an Answer is scope-creeping)